# How to use pysft module in Azure Databricks Notebook

Tags: python, openssl, azure-databricks, pyopenssl, pysftp

I am trying to make a sftp connection using pysftp module in databricks notebook. Here is the code that i had written.

```
import pysftp as sftp

HOSTNAME = my_sftp_hostname
USERNAME = my_sftp_username
PASSWORD = my_sftp_password
FOLDER = dir_to_be_accessed_in

print('HOSTNAME : '+HOSTNAME )
print('USERNAME : '+USERNAME )
print('PASSWORD : '+PASSWORD )
print('FOLDER : '+FOLDER )


cnopts = sftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None   
con = sftp.Connection(HOSTNAME,username=USERNAME,password=PASSWORD, cnopts=cnopts)

print(con)
```

But as i run this code I am getting this error ***TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object***

```
/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pysftp/__init__.py:61: UserWarning: Failed to load HostKeys from /root/.ssh/known_hosts.  You will need to explicitly load HostKeys (cnopts.hostkeys.load(filename)) or disableHostKey checking (cnopts.hostkeys = None).
  warnings.warn(wmsg, UserWarning)
Unknown exception: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 2075, in run
    self.kex_engine.parse_next(ptype, m)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 53, in parse_next
    return self._parse_kexecdh_reply(m)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/kex_ecdh_nist.py", line 136, in _parse_kexecdh_reply
    self.transport._verify_key(K_S, sig)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1886, in _verify_key
    if not key.verify_ssh_sig(self.H, Message(sig)):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/paramiko/rsakey.py", line 134, in verify_ssh_sig
    msg.get_binary(), data, padding.PKCS1v15(), hashes.SHA1()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/rsa.py", line 474, in verify
    self._backend, data, algorithm
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/utils.py", line 41, in _calculate_digest_and_algorithm
    hash_ctx.update(data)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/hashes.py", line 93, in update
    self._ctx.update(data)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/backends/openssl/hashes.py", line 50, in update
    data_ptr = self._backend._ffi.from_buffer(data)
TypeError: from_buffer() cannot return the address of the raw string within a bytes or unicode object
```

I read few blogs but did not get any concrete results. Please let me know if someone has any view on this.

My pysftp version is : 0.2.9 
Paramiko versio is : 2.7.1

Comment: What version of Paramiko/pysftp are you using? Does your code work on a normal machine?

Comment: Yeah the code works fine on normal machine.The version is 0.2.9. I checked the version of pysftp using 

import pysftp
print(pysftp.__version__)

Comment: Please say that in your question, not in comments. + Also please post Paramiko log file from both your normal machine and the azure notebook. + You didn't answer what version of Paramiko are you using.

Comment: I have added he versions for the pysftp and paramiko. But I don't know how to capture the logs for paramiko in databricks. Can you help me on this?

Comment: Are you able to capture logs for the local machine? – I do not know anything about databricks, but it has to have at least some kind of temporary file storage and logging facility, doesn't it?

Comment: No Martin I have not implemented any logging framework to fetch the logs. It just the console output that I receive which is shown as error that i was getting.

Comment: You cannot do any serious development without logging. At least make Paramiko log to some temporary file and then dump its contents to a console.

Comment: @VipendraSingh did you finally make a connection in databricks using pysftp? I am trying to do the same thing but got an authentication error while it worked on my local machine.

Comment: @Nafis, The below answer helped me. Can you paste the complete error you are getting ?

Comment: @VipendraSingh there was some restriction on the remote server I was connecting to. Using less restricted username and password, solved my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The below fix worked for me.**

It looks like a newer version of the cryptography package was installed by default along with another PyPI library, and this cryptography version is incompatible with the version of pyOpenSSL included in Databricks Runtimes.

You can try fixing the compatibility issue of packages, as discussed in the below article. Then try installing the most recent version of pyOpenSSL

https://kb.databricks.com/python/python-exec-display-cancelled.html#problem-module-lib-has-no-attribute-ssl_st_init